# What does "back east" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

How do I go *back* east if I've never been to the east? It does not make sense to return to a place you've never been.

Comment: An american said something about going back east

Comment: Did he say it about himself, like "I'm going back east", or did he tell someone else to "Go back east!"

Comment: He said he is going back east and he said he has never been back east.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In American English, we sometimes say *up north*, *down south*, *out west*, and *back east* when referring to directions. The words *up*, *down*, *out*, and *back* do not have any special meaning in this context, but are often used as a matter of convention. Additionally, the Eastern United States is sometimes referred to as *back east*.

According to this Ngram, it appears that this usage became more common in the latter half of the 19th century, began to decline between 1940 and 1970, and then became more widely used than before:

[image: Ngram]

Comment: Is this a US idiom?  In en_AU we say up/down north/south but not "back east" (and "out west" has a different meaning).  Perhaps because east/west have special significance as Western Australian and the Eastern States

Comment: @trideceth12 It might be. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back+east%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cback+east%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) appears to support that. I'm not certain, but it could have to do with settlers from the Atlantic seaboard moving westward into the territory that was acquired by the US during the 19th century, and then using the word _back_ when describing the East because that was where they were from.

Comment: There's also a New England variant, [down East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_East).

Comment: "Down East" is totally unrelated. It refers to sailing downwind to the east... to Maine. "Back East" would be to return to the culture's (if not their own personal) point of origin -- the originally colonized eastern seaboard, the old country as it were, the sedate and civilized place. You don't personally have to have been from there... a native Californian can talk about "going back east".

Answer (score 3):

"Back east" is a west coast-ism to refer to the east coast, as a corollary to "out west". See e.g. http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/1898/

The underlying source is the idea everyone is somehow "from" the east, and they (or their ancestors) at one point moved "out west", but if they were to return, it would be to go "back east."

Comment: That’s a rather bi-coastal interpretation, eh? :)  I mean, people in the Plains states are perfectly contents to use it to, as is anyone anywhere that people move to from the East. Are you sure you aren’t just displaying Californian bias here? :)

Comment: I'm just reporting how we speak here in California. It's certainly biased, but basically anything east of Utah is "back east".

Answer (score 3):

Most of the settlement of the United States was done by people moving from east to west.  For example, the original 13 states in the United States were along the Atlantic coast.

Yes, the Spanish also colonized Florida, Texas, New Mexico, and California, and the French colonized Louisiana -- but those are exceptions that prove the rule.  In 1803 (when the U.S. purchased Louisiana), the Louisiana Purchase was of territory adjacent to and west of the United States.  In the 1830s, American settlers moving west from Tennessee greatly outnumbered the Spanish-speaking colonists in Texas.  In 1849, a "Gold Rush" of American "49ers" moving west similarly overwhelmed the Spanish-organized Indians around the California missions.

Most of the people who moved west during the settlement of the United States moved to areas where North literally is upstream from South.  Most of the United States is in a huge basin, bounded by the Appalachian mountains in the east, the Great Lakes in the northeast, (roughly) the Canadian border, the Rocky Mountains in the west, and the Gulf of Mexico in the south.  With a few exceptions, most rivers in this region flow southwest, south, or southeast.  In this basin, "downstream" is toward the Gulf of Mexico (that is, toward the "South").

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes "back X" can refer to a cultural or family home, even if one has never been there.

> I'd love to go back to Africa

The implication is that one's culture, or "roots" are in Africa.  However, this is still ambiguous as the speaker might quite rightly assume that the speaker *had* been there before.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some similar answers to this one. I'm not an expert, I'm not even american, but if you watch this video historian Colin Calloway gives some insight as of why this might be such a common term.

Link to video: http://www.choices.edu/resources/scholarsonline/calloway/cc6.php

Comment: Not everyone will be able to view the video (and it might go away at some point), so it may be helpful to extract the points you believe are most insightful and summarize them here.

Comment: I agree that some of the points made in the video should be included in your answer. Listening to a native speaker of a language you're trying to learn can be more difficult than reading the language you're trying to learn, especially when the speaker has a pronounced accent and isn't speaking for an ESL audience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Enumclaw, WA.  To my cohorts and me, "back east" basically refers to anything north of the Carolinas and east of Indiana or Ohio-ish.  It does not reference people who *used to* live on the east coast.  It's a loose geographical reference.  East of the midwest and north of the south is the most common usage, but I have heard people refer to places like Chicago as back east. However, in my humble opinion that would be incorrect usage.